# MicroSoft Excel- Blank cell formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I would like to condition format a row on the criteria that the last cell in the row is blank.

Once text is entered into the cell (O3) I would like to conditional format (Yellow highlight) to go away. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: use rule $O3<>""

Answer (score 0):

*Because last cell reference in Range may vary, therefore first you need to find the cell reference of last cell in the Row to check whether is blank or not.*

- Enter this array (CSE) Formula in any black cell:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(ADDRESS(ROW(A2:O2),MAX((A2:O2="")*COLUMN(A2:O2)),1),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Ehter**.
- Select required Range.
- Use this as **N**ew Rule.

  `=ISBLANK(Cell reference of blank cell)`
- In your case this will `=ISBLANK($O$2)`
- Apply an appropriate cell format & finish with **O**k.

**N.B.**

- *When O2 will blank, Excel apply the format on designated Range, and remove when O2 has value.*
- *Adjust cell reference in the formula as needed.*